# ebay Inventory API returning error "Cannot change an auction to private or vice versa if the item has bid or is ending in 12 hours."

Tags: api, ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

I have integrated eBay [Inventory API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/bulkCreateOrReplaceInventoryItem) for managing the listings of the eBay store. Items are listing successfully but Whenever I tried to update the listing or [offer](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/offer/methods/updateOffer) using their API I am getting the following error in response.

```
Cannot revise the listing. Cannot change an auction to private or vice versa if the item has bid or is ending in 12 hours.
```

I am trying to update a fixed price item not an item in the auction. I searched and found the possible solution [possible solution](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/40528/inventory-api-errorid-25019-on-createorreplaceinve.html) but still no luck. Can anyone please guide me about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not revise the auction offer data if the listing has a bid or going to end in 12 hours. Changing fixed price items is also revising the offer data which is why API is throwing that error. All you can do is end the listing and create another auction with an updated fixed price, however, the fixed price won't be visible if the listing gets any bids.